# Meaning of {0}\\{1} in C# code

Tags: c#, class, console-application

Am working with a file that I haven't written and I'm just trying to understand it. I understand that the below snippet is not much to go by but I'm only confused about one small part.

I'm just wondering for below, what the "{0}\{1}" means, if anyone can help me?

The current result of the code below gives a filepath of c:\Output\Folder\Filename.

```
   private string GetOutputPathForTarget()
        {
            return string.Format("{0}\\{1}", outputDirectory, settings.Name);
        }
```

If I wanted, for example add another subdirectory to this string, would it be as simple as:

```
    private string GetOutputPathForTarget()
    {
        return string.Format("{0}\\{1}", outputDirectory, settings.Name, "Images");
    }
```

Comment: Other than the meaning of "{0}\\{1}", it is important to note that this method should *not* be used to construct file system paths. `Path.Combine` should be used.

Comment: @user289770 - thanks, will take that into account!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those are place holders for the strings you wish to insert into the constant string at specified positions.

Have a look at [String.Format Method (String, Object[])](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1csw23d%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks astander, knew it had to be something like that, I just wasn't sure of the correct way to google it!

Comment: @TaraWalsh: You mean a google search for "C# string format" didn't get you any relevant results? What did you search for if I may ask?

Answer (score 6):

No, this doesn't work. There must be as many placeholders as optional arguments of `string.Format`.

On the other hand, you should use `Path.Combine` to build paths. (See [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.combine.aspx))

Answer (score 4):

`"{0}\\{1}"` is a [format string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txafckwd.aspx) - `{0}` means 'insert the first argument `ToString` here', `{1}` is the same for the second argument.

If you wanted to insert another string, you would need to tell `String.Format` where to insert it:

```
private string GetOutputPathForTarget()
{
    return string.Format("{0}\\{1}\\{2}", outputDirectory, settings.Name, "Images");
}
```

But then I would highly recommend you use [`Path.Combine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.combine.aspx) instead

Answer (score 1):

This is well described in MSDN:

> **[string.Format method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zf3d0ccc.aspx)**

Note that the second sample makes no sense as three parameters are specified but only two are used.

Typically you would use `string.Format` if you want to get a formatted string representation for arbitrary objects or values such as floating point numbers.

We don't know the type of `settings.Name` but if it is of type `string` then the following code is equivalent:

```
return outputDirectory + "\\" + settings.Name;
```

Or:

```
return Path.Combine(outputDirectory, settings.Name);
```

The latter has the advantage that you don't have to worry about the correct path separator and whether a separator is needed or not.

Answer (score 1):

to add a subdirectory, you would need to add another set of `{}`.

```
private string GetOutputPathForTarget()
{
    return string.Format("{0}\\{1}\\{2}", outputDirectory, settings.Name, "Images");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

with `String.Format` it replaces the {0} or {1} with the additional arguments, this creating a composed string.

For example - `string.Format("{0}:{1}-{3}|{4}","a","b","c","d")` would equal `"a:b-c|d"`

For your last requirement, the solution would be:

```
return string.Format("{0}\\{1}\\Images", outputDirectory, settings.Name);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your example is NOT working! Working code would be:

```
return string.Format("{0}\\{2}\\{1}", outputDirectory, settings.Name, "Images");
```

{n} is Replaced by the n-th parameter in the string.Format Function.

But for Building FileNames you should better use:

```
return System.IO.Path.Combine(part1, part2, part3);
```

Kind Regards,
Markus